# Android: modify Download/Bootloader mode

Tags: android, bootloader

Is it possible to modify the Download/Bootloader mode? On my Samsung Note 10.1 I was able to extract the `param.bin`. Since this is only a `tar` file, I could easily unpack it. Inside I found some images similar to [this one](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.galaxynote3update.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Samsung-Galaxy-Note-3-Download-Mode.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.galaxynote3update.com/root-galaxy-note-3-sm-n900-4-3-4-4-2-kitkat-updates/&h=746&w=826&tbnid=ppvYUJEPKHnGvM:&docid=-ZQoWx92kKVfHM&ei=bH2rVszZI4rt-QGV-qLIDw&tbm=isch). In addition, there was a file called `adv-env.img`, which I couldn't figure out how to unpack (if it's even possible). But judging from the images, it seems to me that this is the part that makes up the Download mode.

Does anybody know whether it is maybe possible to unpack this `adv-env.img` file in order to, e.g., block flashing some firmware (i.e., flashing images with odin would always fail)? Or is there any other way to modify the Download mode in a way that flashing would always get blocked?

EDIT: according to the output of `file`, `adv-env.img` is a `dBase IV DBT` file. How can I view the content of it? Can't find a working tool...

Answer (score 0):

What you have in these files is a very processor-specific disk image that loads before any part of Android loads.  Can it be modified?  Anything is possible, but this is an express route to bricking your device.  Unlocking your bootloader and rooting your device are usually the only things you'll need when doing pretty much anything on your device.

As to viewing the file contents, you are doing so when your device boots up.  Other than this, the file is married to your processor architecture, and is binary...there are no usable contents for you within, as far as I know.

Comment: Yeah, I know that I can possibly brick my the device, but I'm okay with that. But do you have any idea how I can modify the Download/Bootloader mode?

Comment: I believe Karim Yaghmour has given presentations on custom bootloaders for Android. I would start my search there!